# roslyn dependenceis MissingMethodException

Tags: .net, roslyn

After upgrading the dependencies in project roslyn compiler started to throw missing method exception in the following code that before update worked:

```
CSharpCompilation compilation = CreateCompilation(templateId, syntaxTrees, metadataReferences);

EmitResult compileResult;
generatedAssembly = string.Empty;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    compileResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
```

Now its throwing MissingMethod exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitResult.get_Diagnostics()'.
```

All the dependencies are updated to current latest versions:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

fds

Comment: Try cleaning your solution.  This would happen if you load the wrong DLL version at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was caused by [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12255) in roslyn, so adding an assembly redirects helped:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Collections.Immutable" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.37.0" newVersion="1.1.37.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

but the app still uses 1.2.0.0 version of Immutable collections

Comment: Project reference for the library in the .csproj also had to change. 
           <Reference Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.1.37\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>